# How we can write sum (Segma) in python?

Tags: python, sum

I would like to please about the easiest way to write  the following equation in python without using `For-loop`

[G''](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFzMd.jpg)

I have used the following code to acheive this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import scipy.optimize as spo
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


N_Prony = 2

w = [10, 20, 30, 50, 60]
g = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

tau = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

G0 = 10

list2=[]

for J in range(len(w)):  
    for i in range(N_Prony):
        GPrime_2 =   G0*((g[i]*((tau[i]))*w[J])/(1+((tau[i]**2))*w[J]**2)*N_Prony) 
    list2.append(GPrime_2)
```

any help!

Comment: Is your list2.append(GPrime_2) indentation is correct?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the question and added an open list for list2 (i.e., list2=[])

Comment: I used append to store the data after each loop in the array list2

Comment: your second loop is not doing anything because you are appending to list2 after the loop ends. You could rewrite it as
```
for J in range(len(w)):
    GPrime_2 =   G0*((g[N_Prony]*((tau[N_Prony]))*w[J])/(1+((tau[N_Prony]**2))*w[J]**2)*N_Prony)
    list2.append(GPrime_2)
```